# How to offset the Y position of every second column in a Grid Control

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

So, this is a standard 5x6 `Grid`.

```
<Grid Width="600" Height="840" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/> 
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Which produces something like this:

[image: Default Grid]

However, I need a way to offset the Y position of every second column to make the end result look like this:

[image]

I'm aware that I could use multiple `Grids` to achieve this, but is there any way this can be done with a single `Grid`? Or even perhaps a different Control?

Thanks

Comment: So simple, I've never needed `Rowspan` before in UWP and was unaware of it. Thanks, if you post as an answer then I'll accept as correct.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the grid rows only half the height, meaning double the rows: The use `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Rowspan` to create your layout. Just span every item over two rows and start every second column at `Grid.Row = "1"`